# org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: Single table query

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am doing a simple query using hibernate.  There are no joins.   All I am trying to do is retrieve the maximum id from a table.   This service was working well for months, but suddenly, within the last two weeks, I get the dreaded No row with the given identifier exists error.   Even though this table contains millions of rows.    How can this be happening?

Here is the service which does the look-up:

```
try {
    session = HibernateUtils.beginTransaction("mydatabase");
    criteria = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class);
    criteria.setMaxResults(1);
    Order order = Order.desc("id");
    criteria.addOrder(order);
    myclass = (MyClass) criteria.uniqueResult();
    } catch (HibernateException e_) {
        e_.printStackTrace();
        String msg = "Problem getting maximum id from myclass table "
            +  e_.getCause();
    LOG.error(msg);
    throw new DataBaseAccessException(msg);
    }finally {
        try {
            HibernateUtils.closeSessions();
        } catch (Exception e_) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you are doing a query on a single table with no joins, it is important to look also at the underlying model involved in the query.    If that model has a join column and the associated foreign key is not present in the joined table, hibernate will fail.

In this case the underlying model is as below:   There is a join column cid that maps to another table code_table.   But there was no corresponding entry in the code_table with the value being queried in the icdtable.   Even though the query was only on the icdtable, the fact that the underlying model joins with another table requires that there be data integrity across the tables not just in the table on which the query is being performed.

```
@Entity
@Table (name="icdtable", catalog="emscribedx")
public class Icdtable {
private Long _icdid;
private Long _cid;
private String _icdcode; //TODO: add this to hibernate mappings ('PN' or 'NN')
private String _status;
private String _create_date;
private String _kstatus;
private int _enterorder;
private String _poa;
private String _ppoa;
private String _userid;
private Code_table _code_table1;
private List<Proceduredetail> _proceduredetails;

@Id
@Column (name = "icdid")
public Long getIcdid() {
    return _icdid;
}
public void setIcdid(Long icdid_) {
    _icdid = icdid_;
}

@Column (name = "cid")
public Long getCid() {
    return _cid;
}
public void setCid(Long cid_) {
    _cid = cid_;
}

@Column (name = "icdcode")
public String getIcdcode() {
    return _icdcode;
}
public void setIcdcode(String icdcode_) {
    _icdcode = icdcode_;
}

@Column (name = "status")
public String getStatus() {
    return _status;
}
public void setStatus(String status_) {
    _status = status_;
}

@Column (name = "create_date")
public String getCreate_date() {
    return _create_date;
}
public void setCreate_date(String createDate_) {
    _create_date = createDate_;
}

@Column (name = "kstatus")
public String getKstatus() {
    return _kstatus;
}
public void setKstatus(String kstatus_) {
    _kstatus = kstatus_;
}

@Column (name = "enterorder")
public int getEnterorder() {
    return _enterorder;
}
public void setEnterorder(int enterorder_) {
    _enterorder = enterorder_;
}

@Column (name = "poa")
public String getPoa() {
    return _poa;
}
public void setPoa(String poa_) {
    _poa = poa_;
}

@Column (name = "ppoa")
public String getPpoa() {
    return _ppoa;
}
public void setPpoa(String ppoa_) {
    _ppoa = ppoa_;
}

@Column (name = "userid")
public String getUserid() {
    return _userid;
}
public void setUserid(String userid_) {
    _userid = userid_;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
public Code_table getCode_table() {
    return _code_table1;
}
public void setCode_table(Code_table code_table_) {
    _code_table1 = code_table_;
}

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "icdtable", targetEntity = Proceduredetail.class, cascade =  CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Proceduredetail> getProceduredetails() {
    return _proceduredetails;
}
public void setProceduredetails(List<Proceduredetail> proceduredetails_) {
    _proceduredetails = proceduredetails_;
}
```

Comment: So Hibernate is performing a join anyways?  Why would it do that, I do not want that, because I expect it would degrade performance.  How do I prevent it from performing an implicit join?

Comment: Lazy loading seems to me the answer on that question