# ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the next query :

```
String queryString = "from Visit vis "
                    + "LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH vis.pdv vis_pdv ";
return query.list();
```

After that, I get the next error when I try to access to some pdv:

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists
```

The point is I have some corrupt data, so "Visit" has sometimes an id in "pdv" but it doesn't exist that pdv in the table "PDV". I would like to handle this in the query, so it doesn't return corrupt data. Is there any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hibernate whene you use join in HQL it returns List so please cast your return satement as return

```
List<Object[]> query.list();
```

and retrun type as

```
List<Object[]>
```

and for your question 
try like this

select vis from Visit vis, Pdv pdv where vis.id=pdv.vis.id

this query will return

```
List<Visit>
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't have in Pdv a reference to Visit, just a reference in Visit to Pdv

Comment: Sorry am not getting, you mean Visit is child table of Pdv? key of Pdv is in Visit or just reference without foreign key constraint

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar issue here: [org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: Single table query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002228/org-hibernate-objectnotfoundexception-no-row-with-the-given-identifier-exists)

Basically the answer is: you need to have a consistent database before Hibernate can work with the data.

I understood that you have a `Visit.pvd` column that is a foreign key into the `PVD` table but contains data that isn't reflected in `PVD`. That's your integrity violation. What you can do is [bypassing Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) and collect any `Visit.id`s that are identifying entities that are invalid:

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT id FROM Visit "
        + "WHERE pvd NOT IN (SELECT p.id FROM pvd)").list();
```

This gets you a `List<Object[]>` that you can iterate to get the offending entities. Use that to `UPDATE` them to not contain invalid references (or just use a plain `UPDATE` with the `WHERE` clause I gave).

Answer (score 0):

> String queryString = "from Visit vis "
>                       + "LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH vis.pdv "; 
>   return query.list();

you dont need `List<Object[]>` as your returning `List<Visit>`

```
List<Object[]>
```

is needed when you are returning multiple object from the query.

eg `select v.pid,v.pname,v.pvisit from Visit v`